# After a week of secondary fermentation of my wine yeast sediment already formed in the carboys. Does it mean I should rack it again soon?

Tags: secondary-fermentation, sediment, country-wine

This is my first brew ever so I'm still learning. I've got two gallons of elderflower wine bubbling now in the carboys for about a week (transferred there after a week long primary in a bucket).

I've noticed that the carboys already formed a couple milimeters of that goopy yeast sediment on the bottom. I've heard that it can introduce some funky flavours into my brew. How worried should I be about that? Should I aim to rack it again to rid of that bottom-yeast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to worry.  Since you already racked your wine once (from primary to secondary) you already gotten rid of most of gross lees.  Fine lees are less problematic, and can remain for a few weeks without problems.

You may rack your wine again to clarify it further.  People usually have a racking schedule, and rack as many times as they want (depends on type of wine).

More information [here](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/21907/how-to-know-when-to-rack-off-gross-lees) and [here](http://winemakersacademy.com/gross-vs-fine-lees)